# Installing wxPython on Pycharm for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm, wxpython

So long story short, I need wxPython for work and we all use PyCharm as the standard IDE so I am backed against the wall for this. I use Pop_OS! which is built off Ubuntu 20.04, so hopefully any other Linux user out there using an Ubuntu based system finds this as well who may need it.

The two solutions I have tried is

1. Using the recommended instructions on wxPython provided here -> https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/index.html. However, the library does not seem to appear and be usable in PyCharm. I was hoping if there would be a way to pip install outside of PyCharm and then import it into PyCharm manually. But my knowledge is lacking here.
2. The second solution was using the Project Interpreter inside PyCharm to download the library. The issue here is that IDE is not able to install wxPython as the error gives back that it attempted but could not run `pip install -U wxPython`
   which is essentially the solution from 1 but inside the PyCharm environment.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The key thing is to choose the correct python interpreter in PyCharm and to make sure to install the desired dependencies, such as wxpython in this case, on that particular interpreter. PyCharm is quite good on understanding different kinds of environment, such as ["standard" virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html), a [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) environment and even some others with plugins (one created with [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/), for instance).

Go to PyCharm interpreter settings (Ctrl+Alt+s) and check which python interpreter is selected and/or choose another interpreter (you might also create a new one if you want). Then install wxwidgets on that interpreter.

I suggest you try using a conda environment. `wxpython` is available in conda and usually when you have problems installing libraries with binary dependencies (that depend on code which is not completely created in Python) its easier to install them with conda.